# How to redirect all requests to subpath with NGINX?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, microservices, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Overview of the application, problem, and goal.**

The application is made up of a network of micro services, wrapped in individual Docker containers. Those containers are Django, Postgres, Nodejs(+ Socket.io), and Nginx+Angular2 (static files). Nginx currently has specific routes for the files and routes all other requests to the Angular2 app, which then has its own router.

Currently the application can be served directly from a root directory but it has to be moved into a sub directory. The address subsequently will include a new path for the directory.

So it works when deployed to...`http://host`, but not with `http://host/path`, as all requests in the microservice gets routed by an NGINX reverse proxy.

How can I use an NGINX rewrite/redirect to append `/path` to the URL so that it can be served from the subdirectory, but NGINX will still know that the locations still exist at the root level?

**My 301 Attempt**

```
  location = / {
    root /www/ng;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    return 301 http://$host/pot;
  }
```

Here I did 301 redirect on the catch all location. It worked for this catch all but when adding the 301 to the static locations, the redirect does not work. Is a 301 the best solution? How would I redirect the static locations?

**Original NGINX conf file**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  root /www/data;

  location /static {
    alias /var/www/static;
  }

  location /media {
    alias /var/www/media;
  }

  location ~* ^/(api|admin) {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://django:8000;
  }

  location /gateway {
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
  }

  location = / {
    root /www/ng;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @ng;
  }

  location @ng {
    root /www/ng;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page 403 /403.html;
  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating instead a symbolic link `ln -s path` ?

Comment: @nbari I haven't. How how would this work in conjunction with Docker volumes? And...wouldn't this conflict with the nginx proxyy?

Comment: give a try, don't know exactly if it will create conflict the thing is that you don't need to modify your nginx for testing